# Creation of indexes in Oracle tablespace after using ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am attempting to replicate an issue where someone is reporting that indexes are failing to be created in the correct tablespace after using a `ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA` call.

connecting as system and calling ddl.sql:

```
sqlplus system/pass@//host/sid @ddl
```

ddl.sql contains:

```
-- setup schema a and user a
@new-db/a_schema_setup
-- setup schema b and user b
@new-db/b_schema_setup

-- creates tables and indexes in schema a
ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA=a;
@new-db/a_ddl

-- creates tables and indexes in schema b
ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA=b;
@common/b_ddl
```

b_ddl.sql contains DDL statements such as

```
CREATE TABLE X (...);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IDX_X_PK ON X(ID);
```

Under what conditions would the indexes not be created in the tablespaces defined for schemas `a` or `b`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have explicitly set the tablespace in the index creation statement e.g.

```
CREATE INDEX table_name_i1
ON table_name (column_one, column_two)
TABLESPACE indexes
/
```

This will override the default you set at the database or schema level.

You could (as Brian says) be using an embedded schema with a different tablespace setting for the indexes (but then these wouldn't be in schema a or b anyway) or have an `ALTER USER b DEFAULT TABLESPACE x` in the script (odd but possible to set this for creating indexes and then set it back, for example).

Answer (score 1):

When the statements include an explicit schema the current one is not used.

```
CREATE TABLE c.X (...);
```